# Item added in Document Library

Tags: document-library, event-receivers

I am trying to update a document library column when adding a document. 
When I press "Take the published document, but create a draft to work on" after this time I want to update a column in my document library?

ItemAdded event handler in a document library:

```
this.EventFiringEnabled=false;
SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
item["DocNum"] = "4321";
item.Update();
this.EventFiringEnabled=true;
```

Comment: What does not work in your code?

Comment: The Field DocNum, does not get updated? @ECM4D

Comment: Is your event receiver called? Have you tried to debug it? Could you explaon more, how do you create your document?

Comment: Yes it is, i have nothing wrong... i upload the document, and add DocNum to the document also, publish it, then when i unpublish it, it should update the DocNum when the document again are added to the drafts list @ECM4D

Comment: If you are publishing document, or adding new item with the same file name, it is updated. So you should use `ItemUpdated` event receiver.

Comment: I have already tried with ItemUpdated the same, when i publish the document it has the orginal DocNum like it should have, when i unpublish the document, i want to change the DocNum

Comment: ItemAdded properties.ListItem has, New value

Answer (score -1):

Modify `item.Update()` as `item.SystemUpdate()`